# What is a relatively LARGE serif or slab font?

Tags: fonts, interface-design, sans-serif, font-size

Please do not downvote without reading the question text. The headline is not as pointless as it may sound.

I'm looking for a **serif** or **slab** font that that comes out relatively large.

For example, a **sans-serif** font that turns out much larger than average fonts at the same pt-size would be Verdana:

[image: Font size comparison, all fonts in 12pt]
All fonts shown at 12pt size

**Edit:** O.k. apparently the question gets downvoted because I didn't explain why I need this.

I would like a relatively large default font in the standard Windows menus.

However, if I set a relatively large font size, say 11 or 12pt, using [Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/how-to-change-menu-row-height-in-windows-10-windows-8-1-and-windows-8/?utm_source=software&utm_medium=in-app&utm_campaign=winaerotweaker&utm_content=menuheight#:%7E:text=In%20addition%2C%20it%20allows%20you%20to%20change%20the%20menu%20font%2C%20which%20cannot%20be%20changed%20with%20a%20Registry%20tweak%2C%20since%20it%20is%20represented%20in%20the%20Registry%20in%20a%20binary%20format.) for example, then the ribbons in Microsoft Office become ridiculously large:
[image: MS Word Ribbon with Menu font size set to 11pt]

I have found that the ribbons are at an optimum size if the Windows menu font is set no larger than 9pt:
[image: MS Word Ribbon with Menu font size set to 9pt]

However, most fonts are so small that then the normal Windows menus in other Programs become tiny.

Therefore, I need a font that, at 9pt size, is as big as an average font at 11pt. I have found this now, for example with Vezus or Sanchez. I did not want to use Verdana because I find it too boring.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? Can't you just adjust font size?

Comment: I added the reason in the question.

Comment: OK, I didn't downvote though. But after you've added the reason your question becomes clear. Not really about graphic design though.

Comment: Up voted to counteract the down votes, but I **don't** think this is a great question - not because there isn't value in the thought behind it. Determining typefaces with larger x-heights can **often** be very helpful. So I do "get it" and understand the reasoning quite well. I think it's a *bad* question because it's essentially a "Shopping List" question -- "find this for me" to a great degree.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the property I was looking for is called "x-height". So the question was not _that_ off-topic in Graphic Design after all.

Comment: OK, I admit that the question isn't completely off-topic.  But since we are going into details now: *x-height* is the height of the lowercase letters. *Cap height* is the height of the uppercase letters. Often when we talk about "fonts with a large x-height", we really mean "fonts with a large x-height/cap height ratio". In other words "fonts where the uppercase letters aren't much taller than the lowercase letters". You *might* want that property for this use, but you mainly have another issue: that fonts aren't necessarily designed at the same size. That's two different things.

Comment: Thanks, that is stuff you don't learn in the more computer related Stack Exchange communities.

Comment: I've removed my downvote, added an upvote, and removed my close vote now that you've explained.  I guess this proves downvotes sometimes get results! In any case, thank you for taking the time to edit your question and explain. I wish more people would do this. It really helps avoid confusion.

Comment: Also given you some upvotes for comments and your answer to help increase your rep score.  And by the way, welcome to GDSE. Please keep contributing and asking questions.  Also don't forget, you can choose your own answer as best!

Comment: Thank you for the kind touch and welcome. I'll be sure to drop by occasionally, and will be happy to discuss topics such as Inkscape, PDF, or vector graphics in general. Be warned, I may occasionally rave about how I believe that .................... PowerPoint is one of the best (say: fastest) vector graphics programs anywhere :‑J

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/does-x-height-really-matter-when-choosing-fonts-for-readability-and-legibility

Comment: A) This question DOES focus on ONE problem (finding large fonts).
B) This question is RESOLVED by my own answer. There is NO reason to close the question due to bad question quality.

Comment: You managing your Windows settings is marginally related here. Also strange you're putting so much energy into something which already works as it is, for like ... half the planet ?

Answer (score 1):

This is called x-height. I remember years ago, when the web was smaller I was comparing default Windows fonts and Verdana was the best. Verdana is a bit wider.
Check IBM Plex (Mono), it is a good display font. My favorite is Mont but whatever. There are so many fonts at this present day.
Looking at Google Font I think Comfortaa can be interesting. Very readable at 12px size.

Comment: Thanks, will try Comfortaa. So many beautiful fonts out there... I feel like I should try and use Germania One as Windows systemwide Font :p https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTykGVB4psMgD-01ZXNIQcjDnTshZ1IRAGgcw&usqp=CAU

Comment: :) https://i.imgur.com/PSFpa85.png

Answer (score 0):

OK found some:

[image: font size comparison]

All fonts at 12pt again.

Vezus is the current winner, size-wize.

I surely love me those slab fonts in menus:

[image: Vezus 9pt]
Vezus 9pt

[image: MetronicSlab 10pt]
Metronic Slab 10pt

[image: Museo Slab 10pt]
Museo Slab 10pt

[image: Sanchez 10pt]
Sanchez 10pt

Comment: Interesting look, maybe because it's new to you but if we follow proper design principles, these slab fonts are made for titles. I think serif fonts and slabs will eventually disappear because serif/slab parts will be seen as visual noise.